# How to stop the player from jumping while in the air?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I don't want my player to jump in the air but I can't seem to find anything out.

This is what I have. They can jump, but they can jump forever and that's a problem.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
  public float speed = 5f;
  public float jumpSpeed = 8f;
  private float movement = 0f;
  public bool alive;
  private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;
  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
    rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        // Use this for initialization
    }


  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {
    movement = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    if (movement > 0f) {
      rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
    }
    else if (movement < 0f) {
      rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
    } 
    else {
      rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (0,rigidBody.velocity.y);
    }
    if(Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")){
      rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.velocity.x,jumpSpeed);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the Jump button press, you assign a new velocity to Rb.  So when you are using velocity.y from there on out, velocity.y is always equal to `jumpSpeed`.  A jump is usually implemented using `AddForce`

Comment: @jiveturkey if you came from unity3d its 2d cause stack want to work against me and I want to make it so a player can only jump on the ground

Comment: Do you have some way to detect if the character is on the ground?  If so, check the flag, if NOT on the ground, get out and don't add velocity or force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An simple option is to maintain a boolean such as `_inAir` that gets set to `true` when the player first jumps, and to `false` when their `RigidBody2D` collides with the ground (see, e.g., [OnCollisionEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html)).

Then, the check `if(Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")){` becomes

```
if (!_inAir && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
```